# VPS server -> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, centos, vps

when we try this code in **hosting server** its perfectly work,
but we move code to **VPS server godaddy** it gives error

```
Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in  
/public_html/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php on line 135
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /public_html/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php:135)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 573 
 Backtrace: 

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error
Message:  Call to undefined function mysqli_init()
Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
Line Number: 135
Backtrace:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into WHM on the VPS and install the mysqli extension. You can do that using EasyApache as described here...

https://www.godaddy.com/help/enabling-apache-or-php-modules-using-easyapache-6237

Comment: thanks for help, MySQLi is disabled, after enable its works perfect